# Issues with .h files in C

Tags: c, custom-headers

I created a sample .h file in C and it didn't work, for some reason. The files are as follows:

header.c:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "header.h"
int add(int a, int b) {
int tmp=a;
int i;
for(i=0, i==tmp, i++) {
b++;
}
return(b);
}
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

int add(int a, int b);
#endif
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"
int main(void) {
int foo=add(1, 2);
printf("%i \n", foo);
return(0);
}
```

When I try to compile main.c with make and gcc it says that add is undefined. Help!

Comment: `gcc -std=C11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -o main main.c header.c` - now what does *yours* look like?

Comment: Either?? Either *what* ? I only posted one command line.

Comment: It is possible that your Makefile is incorrect. Are you compiling both `.c` files?

Comment: make main or gcc -O3 -g main.c -o <output file>

Comment: `header.c` isn't going to compile itself by inference. Either your makefile or your direct command line needs to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the header file only includes the function prototype. You need to link the actual definition of `add()` by compiling separate object files or you can compile them together in a single command line:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra header.c main.c -o main
```

Perhaps, you may want to consider [Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefiles.html) for larger projects.

Your `add()` function has issues:

1) Semi-colons `;` are used in for loops, not commas.
2) The condition should be `i!=tmp` for addition.

This:

```
for(i=0, i==tmp, i++) { .. }
```

should be

```
for(i=0; i!=tmp; i++) { .. }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile both main.c and header.c into the same executable:

```
all: main

main: main.o header.o
    gcc -o main main.o header.o

header.o: header.c header.h
    gcc -c header.c

main.o: main.c header.h
    gcc -c main.c
```

Or for a one-liner without a make file:

```
gcc -g -o main main.c header.c
```

Comment: I would expect the compile step to include a '-I,' parameter to tell gcc where tghe user header file is located

Answer (score 1):

You need to add header.c to the compile call.  You can't just compile main.c.

Comment: Thanks y'all. I literally just finished learning C and was way lost... thanks!